# Show that the sequence $a_n\leq a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

We are given a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $0\lt a_n\leq a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}$ for all natural numbers $n$. Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges.

---

I attempted the question as follows. Consider, say,
$$\begin{align}
S_7 &=  a_1+(a_2+a_3)+(a_4+a_5)+(a_6+a_7)\\
  &\geq a_1+a_1+(a_2+a_3)\\
  &\geq a_1+a_1+a_1
\end{align}$$

But I have no idea how to generalise this to show that the sequence diverges.

Comment: You're not new here -- you must know the guidelines... what are *your* thoughts on the question?

Comment: **Hint:** Try a proof by contradiction. Suppose the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges to $\ell$. Now, try to arrive at a contradiction using the mentioned inequality.

Comment: **Hint #2:** Notice that if the series converges, we have $\ell\leq\ell -a_1$ and furthermore we know that $a_1\gt 0$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas - Sorry but how did you arrive at $l\leq l-a_1$?

Comment: @KaranKaran I guess, by summing the inequality from $n=1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: @KaranKaran, read my first comment on this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you found can indeed be generalized. Here is a hint:

Take any natural number $n$.

Then $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{2^{n+1}-1} a_k = a_1 + \sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1} ( a_{2k}+a_{2k+1} ) \ge a_1 + \sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1} a_k$.

Thus $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1} a_k - \sum_{k=1}^{2^0-1} a_k \ge n·a_1$, by induction.